# Save Excel file in project root directory

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am creating Excel file in asp.net . I want to save excel file in my project root directory .Problem is that it is throwing an exception " Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\OrderDetails.xls' is denied. "
My code

```
Wbook.WriteXLS(".../OrderDetails.xls");
```

But when I use Path

```
 Wbook.WriteXLS("D://OrderDetails.xls");
```

It works . But I don't want to save in drive D . I want to save this in my project .

Comment: Are you running this on the server in IIS? Or on a development machine?

Comment: `...` isn't a valid path; but you shouldn't install the Office suite in a server machine. Explore another options, like openXML

Comment: I am running this on IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have access to the folder your project is in. Go to the folder in Windows Explorer, open up properties, make sure the folder is NOT read-only, and then make sure your user has all the necessary privileges under the "Security" tab.